# Subscriber is not a functional interface

Tags: java, reactor

I have the following code. Why is it that, while Flux extends from Publisher, I cannot use a lambda on the subscribe method of the publisher, while I can on the Flux?

```java
        Publisher<String> publisher = new Publisher<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext("Hello world");
                subscriber.onNext("Hello world");
                subscriber.onNext("Hello world");
                subscriber.onNext("Hello world");
                subscriber.onComplete();
            }
        };
        //this lines gives me an error "Subscriber<String> is not a functional interface" 
        publisher.subscribe(System.out::println);

        //no error on this line 
        Flux.just("a","b","c","d")
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Publisher.subscribe` takes a `Subscriber` as a parameter, which is not a functional interface.

`Flux` has an overloaded `subscribe` method which takes a `Consumer` as a parameter, which *is* a functional interface. You are in fact using this latter version in your last line.

See [Javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-)